# JSON Serde Parsing Array Struct Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, bigdata

My JSON Object:

```
{
    "_total": 4,
    "values": [
        {
            "total-follower-count": 63911,
            "organic-follower-count": 6000,
            "paid-follower-count": 3911,
            "time": 1399334400000
        },
        {
            "total-follower-count": 64023,
            "organic-follower-count": 6000,
            "paid-follower-count": 4023,
            "time": 1399420800000
        },
        {
            "total-follower-count": 64023,
            "organic-follower-count": 6000,
            "paid-follower-count": 4023,
            "time": 1399507200000
        },
        {
            "total-follower-count": 64048,
            "organic-follower-count": 6000,
            "paid-follower-count": 4048,
            "time": 1399593600000
        }
    ]
}
```

In AWS Athena, I created a table like below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Linkedindata 
(
  `_total` INT,
   values array<struct<total_follower_count:INT,
                       organic_follower_count:INT,
                       paid_follower_count:INT>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "mapping.total_follower_count"="total-follower-count",
  "mapping.organic_follower_count"="organic-follower-count", 
  "mapping.paid_follower_count"="paid-follower-count" 
  )
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

I'm unable to access Array values like "Total_Follower_count". Could you please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten your arrays and perform your select on that.

Documented with clear example here,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did try using below script but it returns nothing.     select
 _total,
 unnested_series.valuesentry.total_follower_count
 
from
 linkedindata t
 cross join unnest(t.values) unnested_series (valuesentry)